# I want to have my c program scheduling other programs with specific CPU usage

Tags: c, operating-system, cpu-usage

My program as of now just executes other c program.But I want this process to take the (inputted value)% of CPU.As of now the new processes(forked processes) take only 0%of CPU..sometimes 0.1%.I want it to take the inputted% ex..25%

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


  printf("u_interval=%d\n", u_interval);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < schedulees_count; ++i) {
    schedulee_t *schedulee = schedulees[i];
    printf("schedulee %zu: %d%%\n  argv: [", i, schedulee->proportion);
    for (size_t j = 0; schedulee->argv[j] != NULL; ++j) {
      printf("\"%s\", ", schedulee->argv[j]);
    }
    printf("\b\b]\n");
    int pid = fork(); //The parent(>0) and child(0) is formed
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Hello from Child!\n"); 
        execv(schedulee->argv[0], schedulee->argv);
      }

    // parent process because return value non-zero. 
    else{
      wait(NULL);
        printf("Hello from Parent!\n"); 
              schedulee->pid = pid;
              kill(pid,SIGSTOP);

      }    
  }
```

This is a part of the program where it executes the other programs(task) through the execv command.But the new process only takes 0.0%of CPU.I want it to have 25% of CPU usage for example.

Comment: Unless the program is running with extra privileges, it can't override the operating system's priority algorithm.

Comment: If you stop the child, it won't use any CPU until you make it continue.

Comment: If you want to control the child's scheduling etc, think about whether [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) is of any use to you (along with [`posix_spawnattr_setschedparam()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawnattr_setschedparam.html) and [`posix_spawnattr_setschedpolicy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawnattr_setschedpolicy.html), etc). Or use [`setschedparam()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setschedparam.html) etc in the child.

Comment: If you want to use LOTS of CPU, then two things have to happen: 1) the desired program must be run at a higher priority and 2) the program needs to be 'cpu bound' I.E. not 'I/O bound'

Comment: regarding: `execv(schedulee->argv[0], schedulee->argv);`  In general, any call to any of the `exec*` functions needs to be followed by: `perror( "exec* failed" ); followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  so the child code does not execute any of the parent code, when the `exec*` function fails

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  There is no function definition, only a bunch of 'random' code

Comment: regarding: `int pid = fork();`  The function `fork()` has three kinds of returned values.  The posted code handles >0 and ==0, but fails to handle <0

Comment: @user3629249 This is just a part of the program..There are more lines above..Only if you execute that the program will compile.